# Select data from two date ranges SQL

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, teradata

Using SQL, I want to only pull data for Today-10 days as well as last year (same week) minus 10 days.

see thought process below:

```
WHERE 
(report_date BETWEEN current_date AND current_date(-10)) OR 
(report_date BETWEEN current_date(-365) AND current_date(-375))
```

thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?  It makes a big difference.  Also, are you only ever going to go back one year, or do you want the same 10 day period over multiple years?

Comment: I'm using Teradata. I only want to look at one year back. I would also prefer to use week instead of counting 365 days back but don't know how to notate that.

Comment: Is `report_date` a date field or datetime field?

Comment: just a date field. the below worked, apparently I was just overusing parenthesis.

Comment: What do you mean by " I would also prefer to use week instead of counting 365 days back..."?

Comment: Instead of using -365 which isn't a very accurate comparison period, i'd prefer to use something that looks at the same week, just last year.

current_date(weeknumber)
current_date(weeknumber - 52)

Comment: How do you define a week and *same week, just last year*? What if there's a week 53?

Comment: I don't think Teradata has a year function, but there's add_months (https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/wpx1472240935704.html) which you could use with -12 to go back a year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE
    (report_date BETWEEN current_date - 10 AND current_date)
OR
    (report_date BETWEEN current_date - 375 AND current_date - 365)
```